# undefined reference to const int within shared_ptr

Tags: c++, c++17, definition, constexpr, one-definition-rule

I have a Config class

```
// config.hpp

class Config {
  public:
    static constexpr int a = 1;
    static constexpr int b = 1;
}
```

and include in main.cpp

```
// main.cpp
#include "config.hpp"
int main () {
  std::cout << Config::a << std::endl; // this is ok
  std::shared_ptr<otherClass> stream = std::make_shared<otherClass>( 
Config::a); // compile error
}
```

and compiler said that `undefined reference to Config::a`

and it works when using `cout`, but not work when within `shared_ptr` constructor.

I have no idea why this happens.

Comment: You need to define `a` at namespace scope like a static member prior to c++17, ie `constexpr int Config::a;`

Comment: Why `cout` works?

Comment: It's an unfortunate consequence of perfect forwarding and odr-usage that makes the `make_shared` not work. `make_shared<otherClass>(int(Config::a))` will also work

Comment: ok. hope you explain that in detail. thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that [std::make_shared](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared) takes parameter by reference, which causes `Config::a` to be [odr-used](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition#ODR-use) because it'll be bound to the reference parameter, then its definition at namespace scope is required (before C++17).

On the other hand, `std::cout << Config::a` won't cause `Config::a` to be odr-used, because [std::basic_ostream::operator<< (int)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt) takes parameter by value, `Config::a` is then subject to lvalue-to-rvalue conversion requested to copy-initialize the parameter, therefore `Config::a` is not odr-used.

If an object is odr-used, its definition must exist. You can add the definition (in an implementation file) as

```
constexpr int Config::a; // only necessary before C++17
```

Note that it cannot have an initializer.

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/QJw6Fe6rBe7mHoft)

Since C++17 [`constexpr` static data member](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static#Constant_static_members) is implicitly inline then such definition is not required again, so your code works well from C++17.

> If a `static` data member is declared `constexpr`, it is implicitly `inline` and does not need to be redeclared at namespace scope. This redeclaration without an initializer (formerly required as shown above) is still permitted, but is deprecated.

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/DiXWNXjRMwq1pWoC)

Comment: Note that the definition at namespace scope can't be in the header file; it must be in a .cpp file you link with everything else.

Answer (score 1):

Your a is private, and either a public: needs to preceed it or make the class a struct to get default public.  But this compiles under C++14
https://godbolt.org/g/tS4M1Z

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

struct Config {
  static constexpr int a = 1;
  static constexpr int b = 1;
};

struct otherClass {
    otherClass( int c ) { }
};

int main () {
  std::cout << Config::a << std::endl; // this is ok
  std::shared_ptr<otherClass> stream = std::make_shared<otherClass>( Config::a ); // compile error
}
```

Comment: Yes, the issue probably actually has to do with multiple translation units. If the constructor for otherClass is in a different cpp file, then this won't work in C++14.